# Where to place .mp4 files in Nexus 7?

Tags: file-system, mp4

I have connected my Nexus 7 to my Macbook, and I am using the app Android File Transfer.

I want to place an .mp4 movie, but I am not sure where to place it. I have tried placing it in the Movies folder, but then when I go into my Nexus and go to Play Movies and TV, is not there.

Where am I supposed to place that file, so that I can open it from Nexus?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [Google Play Movies & TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.videos)? I think this is only for rented / purchased movies in Google Play.

To play an MP4 file on your device, try an app like [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad).

Comment: With an app like MX Player, or VLC, you can place your video file anywhere in the device and the app can open it. But it would be easier to keep all your video files in one folder such as Videos or Movies so that apps which does indexing can index all the videos in that folder automatically for easy browsing.